# Remove specific data from field without overwriting entirely

Tags: mysql

I have a field in a table for Shortlisted jobs. When the user adds the job to the shortlist, it'll add the ID separated by comma.

For example: `"1, 2, 3, 4, 5"`

Let's say the customer removes a job from their shortlist, I need to remove the value in the field, without removing the others ID's.

So if we remove ID 4, I'd need it to update the field value to: `"1, 2, 3, 5"`

To add the data, I'm using the current query:

```
UPDATE users SET shortlist = concat(shortlist, '".$r['jobid'].",') WHERE uid='".$row['uid']."'
```

I'm assuming there would be something along the lines of what I've done above to achieve this however I can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually one would create a join table for this time of operation. Say a table like `users_jobs` which has `user_id` and `job_id` - it's a much more solid structure. It's much easier to delete a row from a table than it is to mess with a bad data structure.

Comment: @skrilled I did have this structure before, however I thought it'd save data by inserting the `jobid` into a field specific to the user. I'd then explode the comma for each `jobid` and display the results on their shortlist page.

Comment: Doing this in SQL is really difficult. Do it in PHP. Select the value, explode it, remove the item you don't want, implode that, and update the table.

Comment: @MattyClarke You're saving bytes, maybe kilobytes / and even that is arguably better and more efficient. The original structure you had is much better. As it stands you have to run two queries to do what you could do in one (list all the jobs for a user). You have to do multiple queries and combine php code to implode/explode to remove a job too this way, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating the list in PHP, you can also modify it using PHP.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT shortlist FROM users WHERE uid = :uid");
$stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$shortlist = explode($row['shortlist']);
$pos = array_search('4', $shortlist);
if ($pos !== false) {
    unset($shortlist[$pos]);
    $shortlist_str = implode($shortlist);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET shortlist = :shortlist WHERE uid = :uid");
    $stmt->execute(':uid' => $uid, ':shortlist' => $shortlist_str));
}
```